# Postgres problem with insert if not exist

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to insert if not exist from variables but I am getting the error message:

Syntaxerror at "where"

I can´t use on conflict because I don´t have a primary key which I can use as it always depends on Sensorid and channelid

```
foreach($p in $pingchannel){
$sensorid=$p.sensorid
$channelid=$p.Id
$channelname=$p.Name
$Unit=$p.Unit 
$lastvalue=$p.lastvalue
$PercentMode=$p.PercentMode
$PercentValue=$p.PercentValue
$Factor=$p.Factor


$QueryTypes='
Insert Into "channels" (
sensorid,
"channelid",
"channelname",
"unit",
"lastvalue",
"percentmode",
"percentvalue",
"factor"
)


Values (
'+$sensorid+',
'+$channelid+',
'''+$channelname+''',
'''+$Unit+''',
'''+$lastvalue+''',
'''+$PercentMode+''',
'''+$PercentValue+''',
'''+$Factor+'''
)

where not exists (select sensorid,channelid from channels where sensorid=$sensorid and channelid=$channelid); '

 $DBCmd = $connection.CreateCommand();
 $DBCmd.CommandText   =$QueryTypes
 $DBCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
 $DBCmd.ExecuteReader();
 }
```

any Idea?

Comment: There is no `WHERE`  in `INSERT` ([Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-insert.html)). Make `SELECT` first to see if the searched values exists...

Comment: "I can´t use on conflict because I don´t have a primary key" — Then create a unique constraint. That's the proper solution anyway, you can't rely on application code to keep data integrity.

Comment: ok I just found out how to create a unique constraint, thank you Alvaro. I know changed the query to

Comment: You're still trying to guess syntaxes. In Philippe's link you can see that you need to provide a full `UPDATE` clause so PostgreSQL knows what fields to update and what values to use.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use WHERE in this way on PostgreSQL.
The only way WHERE fits on an INSERT is when you insert values got from a select like this:

```
insert into LeadCustomer (Firstname, Surname, BillingAddress, email)
select 
    'John', 'Smith', 
    '6 Brewery close, Buxton, Norfolk', 'cmp.testing@example.com'
where not exists (
    select 1 from leadcustomer where firstname = 'John' and surname = 'Smith'
);
```

So you can adapt your query to the example above, using the input values on SELECT statement.

But, as mentioned in the comments above, if you have access to change de table, you should create a unique id between sensorid and channelid. This would solve the problem in the proper way and avoid this whole thing on insert.

Comment: There is no way this SELECT statement can work, it can't see uncommitted data from concurrent INSERT statements.

Comment: @FrankHeikens, it isn't looking for any uncommited data, it's seraching for data already on the table

Comment: That's exactly why you can still have records that are not unique.

Comment: well, I totally agree with this, just trying to help in case the guy can't create unique id.